# Java Jackson encoder type mismatched type because of array

Tags: java, json, jackson, lombok

I make client to backend (unfortunately I can not change it) and it sends a structure like:

```json
{ 
   "code":"Success",
   "structure": {
       "sth":"sth"
   }
}
```

but when code is `Error` it returns:

```json
{ 
   "code":"Error",
   "structure":[]
}
```

Because of this array it's hard to deserialize it. I tried in this way:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
class Structure {
    private String code;
    private Sth structure;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@JsonIgnoreType
class Sth{
    private String sth;
}
```

But `JsonIgnoreType` always ignores `Sth` not only in situation it's incompatible type...
Have you maybe any idea?

#Edit

Error message:

> 2021-09-02 11:56:28.623 DEBUG [http-nio-8021-exec-2] [package]: [function] com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `package.class$StructurePayload` out of START_ARRAY token
> at [Source: (BufferedReader); line: 1, column: 113] (through reference chain: Structure["structure"])

Comment: Does `Error` contain array of strings, numbers, or `Sth`?

Comment: it seems that `structure` is an object in one response and an array in the other. I'm not sure jackson has an option to handle this, it's a pretty bad API. You can maybe try with a custom deserializer, and make `structure` an `Object`, that's what I would try.

Comment: Not exactly this JSON code is from one of the dirties backend which i saw... This could send you from the same enpoint json or html depends on what it would like to...

Answer (score 0):

I fix this issue by creating special JacksonDeserializer like

```
public class StartShiftResponseDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer {

    @Override
    public type deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
       ...
        try {
            ...
        } catch (MismatchedInputException e) {
            Sth= null;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            Sth= null;
        }
        return new Structure (..., Sth);
```

And it works pretty good ;)